# Software Testing Tools - for java

Tags: java, testing

Can someone list me 5 good softwares for "Software Testing" in java projects? I need to study 5 of them, what do you recommend?

Answer (score 13):

- Unit test frameworks: [JUnit](http://www.junit.org/) / [TestNG](http://testng.org/)
- Mocking frameworks: [JMock](http://www.jmock.org/) / [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/) / [Mockito](http://mockito.org/)
- Continuous Integration tools: [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) / [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/)
- Requirements testing: [Fit](http://fit.c2.com/) / [FitNesse](http://fitnesse.org/)
- Code coverage: [Cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/)
- Automated UI testing: [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)
- Other tools: [HTTPUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/) / [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/)
- Mutation Testing [PITest](http://pitest.org/)
- Contract tester: [EqualsVerifier](http://code.google.com/p/equalsverifier/) (Ok, full disclosure: I made this one myself.)

Answer (score 4):

To start off, the [jUnit](http://www.junit.org/) unit testing framework.

However, there are many different tools, depending on the type of testing you are doing.

[Here](http://java-source.net/open-source/testing-tools) is a good list.

Answer (score 1):

[Mutation Testing](http://www.mutationtest.net/twiki/bin/view/Resources/WebHome) is a neat idea.

My preference is to catch bugs before testing via [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/), [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/), and [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/).

For unit testing [JUnit](http://junit.org/) or [TestNG](http://testng.org/).

To ensure that unit tests are testing a fair chunk of the code a code coverage tool such as [cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/) or [EMMA](http://emma.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: +1 Do you use checkstyle, PMD and FindBugs in conjunction?

Comment: yes, there is some overlap, but for the most part each has a different focus.

Answer (score 0):

- JUnit
- DBUnit
- HttpUnit
- Selenium
- SoapUI

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the unit testing tools already listed in the other answers, you may want to read about functional testing as well. For, example: [Quick Test Pro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_QuickTest_Professional)

The test scripting language in Quick Test Pro is VB Script. but the created tests can be run against any GUI application, including Java GUIs.