# Software Testing

Tags: java, testing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software Testing Tools - for java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572085/software-testing-tools-for-java)

I am just reading about testing and wanted to know what all softwares/packages are available for different types of testing

The only thing i know is jUnit/TestNG for unit testing.

I'm mainly looking for testing Java applications.

Comment: I think you need to be a little more explicit in your question. What do you mean by "testing java applications", unit, integration, UI??? There are literally hundreds of testing frameworks, apis, tools, applications, etc. It just depends on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the top of my head:

- Mocking Frameworks (Easymock, JMock, Mockito)
- Gui Testing Stuff: Selenium
- There is stuff for load testing (JMeter I think)
- Depending on your definition of testing you might also be interested in static code analysis (Sonar, pmd, findbugs, checkstyle, Jdepend)
- Code Coverage Tools: Emma

Pretty much everything you want probably exists

Comment: Also, XMLUnit and DBUnit. Jcoverage is also a good code coverage tool.

Answer (score 1):

[JUnit](http://www.junit.org/) is good unit testing. I have seen any many projects it is widely used.

Comment: already mentioned in the question ;-) Consider to change it to a comment ...

Answer (score 0):

The question should not be about what packages to use, but how to test IMO. jUnit and jMock will give you everything you need.

There are more of course, but these are good start to understand what you want.

Check this about some insight about testing http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html (it focuses about mocking, but you will get overall idea about testing).

Answer (score 0):

- HtmlUnit similar to selenium
- Benerator for test data generation
- Ejb3Unit
- SoapUI for webservice testing

Have a look here for more suggestions - http://java-source.net/open-source/testing-tools

Answer (score 0):

- TEST MANAGEMENT TOOL "Quality Center"
- TEST EXECUTION TOOLS "QTP"
- PERFORMANCE MEASUREMENT TOOLS "Loadrunner"
- REQUIREMENTS MANAGEMENT TOOLS "
- CONFIGURATION MANAGEMENT TOOL "SourceAnywhere"
- REVIEW TOOL "InView"
- STATIC ANALYSIS TOOLS "PMD"
- MODELING TOOLS "Altova ; ER"
- Test Data Preparation Tools "Clone & Test"
- Test Harness / Unit Test Framework Tools "Junit"
- Coverage Measurement Tool "CodeCover"
- Security Tools "Fortify"